# phpBB3 Developing - Where to start?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm trying to start building a whole application using phpBB3 user system as a base using CodeIgniter framework. However before starting I would like to hear a piece of **advice** from any phpBB3 Developer out there.

I've been developing for Wordpress and Drupal. But recently I decided I would build up something fit to my needs instead of using a premade application.

***The application is going to include:***

- Article System
- Video Streaming
- Wiki
- User editable Profiles
- and much more

## To any phpBB3 Developer :

- Where to start?
- Any recommendation you could give me?
- Any tips?

Comment: What do you mean by INSTEAD of using a premade application. Isn't phpBB3 exactly that?

Comment: phpBB3 has an API, I would probably not start meddling with the codebase since phpBB is not really known for well written code.

Comment: @tharkun: premade as in using the "out of the box" thing. For example, the blog or the Profiles. In this case all I'm going to use is the user system and probably the forum. But that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only used phpBB3 as a forum system, but you should definitely check out the [phpBB Development Wiki](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Main_Page), particularly the [API](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Category:API) section.

It has all sorts of neat things, like how to [add custom pages](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Add_custom_page) and [use phpBB's permission system](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Permissions).